# Variável não exibe resultado correto em C

Tags: c, array, matriz

Tenho o seguinte problema para resolver:
Escreva um programa que faz a leitura de duas matrizes de 10 linhas e 2 colunas. Cada linha da
matriz armazena duas notas de um aluno. A primeira matriz armazena as notas de G1 e a segunda as
notas de G2. Após a leitura das duas matrizes calcule a média final de cada um dos alunos e
armazene em um vetor de 10 posições. Importante a média das notas é aritmética. Escreva o vetor
resultante na tela. Importante: a nota final de G1 é obtida pela média das duas notas da matriz G1. A
nota de G2 é obtida pela média das duas notas da matriz de G2.

Realizei o que foi pedido, no entanto na hora de exibir o resultado da `media[i]` só é mostrado o valor 0 em todas os índices do vetor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
int m1[10][2], m2[10][2];
int soma[10], soma2[10], media[10], result[10], result2[10];
int l, c, i, j;

printf ("\n Notas G1 \n");
for (l=0; l<10; l++)
{
    for (c=0; c<2; c++)
    {
        printf ("\n Aluno [%d], nota [%d]: ", l+1,c+1);
        scanf ("%d", &m1[l][c]);
        soma[l] += m1[l][c]; //soma notas g1
        result[l] = soma[l] / 2; 
    }
}

printf ("\n Notas G2 \n");

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        printf ("\n Aluno [%d], nota [%d]: ", i+1,j+1);
        scanf ("%d", &m2[i][j]);
        soma2[i] += m2[i][j]; // soma notas g2
        result2[i] = soma2[i] / 2;
    }
}

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    media[i] = (result[i] + result2[i])/2; //media
}

for (i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    printf ("\n Media dos aluno [%d]: %.2f", i,media[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Como está a tipagem das variáveis?

Answer (score 2):

Os vetores media, result e result 2 deveriam ser do tipo float.
Outra coisa que pode causar problemas: levando em consideração que

```
soma[l] += m1[l][c];
```

é a mesma coisa que

```
soma[l] = soma[l] + m1[l][c]
```

e não foi atribuído um valor a soma[l], soma[l] pode receber um valor aleatório, então sugiro que você atribua o valor 0 a soma[l] antes de somar as notas:

```
printf ("\n Notas G1 \n");
for (l=0; l<10; l++)
{
    soma[l] = 0;
    for (c=0; c<2; c++)
    {
        printf ("\n Aluno [%d], nota [%d]: ", l+1,c+1);
        scanf ("%f", &m1[l][c]);
        soma[l] += m1[l][c]; //soma notas g1
        result[l] = soma[l] / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas como fazer com que o vetor soma[l] receba 0?

Comment: depois de entrar no loop for (l=0; l<10; l++) e antes de entrar no loop for (c=0; c<2; c++), você coloca, soma[l] = 0, vou editar minha resposta pra você ver.

Comment: Entendi, mas continua não exibindo o resultado :/

Comment: a saída ainda é zero pra todos os itens do vetor?

Comment: mude os tipos das matrizes m1 e m2 e dos vetores soma e soma2 para float também

Comment: Para esse problema, modifique todas as variáveis que vão participar do cálculo para a tipagem float.

Comment: Deveriam mesmo ser do tipo `float`? Notas não são as melhores coisas para se por em ponto flutuante, normalmente seria usado ponto fixo mesmo.